# how do we detect a user has cleared the browser data (clear site data button) in javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browser

I need to listen to the event if user clear the browser data.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZY2d.png)

Comment: There is no event for that. All you can do is check to see if data your app has added (session storage/local storage/cookie) is available, and then take the appropriate action.